# Dropdown clicked only selected rows

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have crated table with weather data using php and openweathermap. I would like to show only first row from each day. After clicking on selected row only content belonging within selected date is dropping down.

At this moment I have managed to create table with visible only first rows from each day and dropdown all hidden content at one moment. 
How can I dropdown content belonging to chosen row section (date)?

My code to download data and create table:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
use Cmfcmf\OpenWeatherMap;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$lang = 'pl';
$units = 'metric';
$owm = new OpenWeatherMap("MY_KEY");
$forecast = $owm->getWeatherForecast('Warszawa', $units, $lang, '', 3);
?>
<table class="pogoda">
<tr>
<th><?php echo "Data:"; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Godzina:"; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Temperatura: "; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Ciśnienie: "; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Wilgotność: "; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Prędkość wiatru: "; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Kierunek wiatru: "; ?></th>
<th><?php echo "Zachmurzenie: "; ?></th>
</tr>
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = NULL;
foreach ($forecast as $weather) {
if($j == $weather->time->day->format('d.m.Y')){
$i = 1; 
}
if($i == 0){
echo '<tr class="dropdown">'; 
echo '<td>' . $weather->time->day->format('d.m.Y') . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->time->from->format('H:i') . " - " . $weather->time->to->format('H:i') . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->temperature . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->pressure . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->humidity . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->wind->speed . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->wind->direction . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->clouds . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$i = 0;
}
else{
echo '<tr class="dropdown-content">'; 
echo '<td>' . $weather->time->day->format('d.m.Y') . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->time->from->format('H:i') . " - " . $weather->time->to->format('H:i') . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->temperature . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->pressure . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->humidity . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->wind->speed . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->wind->direction . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $weather->clouds . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$i = 0;
}
$j = $weather->time->day->format('d.m.Y');
}
?>
```

css:

```
tr.dropdown-content{
  display: none;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr.dropdown").click(function(){
        $("tr.dropdown-content").slideToggle('fast');

    });
});
```

Comment: Add an identifier in row `<tr class='row-date-01-02'>` which can be mapped with your dropdown `<option value='01-02'>Today</option>` value... It's just an outline.

Comment: It appears you only have either `dropdown` or `dropdown-content` appearing at a time, but your javascript requires them both to be. You instead can always echo a `<tr class='dropdown'><td colspan="8"></td></tr>` at the top, before testing if i==0? Then, yes, add the class to the row as Vishal suggests.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu could you be more specific? - it this rather hard because there are 8 possible ways to place new day. Maybe there is a way with js?

Comment: It is easy to be done with JS. and you need to identify your rows and values to let javascript handle the rest.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try to change code to let javascript identify the right rows :)

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply changed the js code to:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("tr.dropdown").click(function(){
            $(this).nextUntil('tr.dropdown').slideToggle('normal');
    });
    });
```

It solved the problem.